# Time Complexity for Conversion to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: time-complexity

Most of the questions here seem to deal with converting a specific CFG to CNF. But I was looking online and couldn't find an answer to the time complexity for this. What is the run time complexity for converting any given CFG to Chomsky Normal Form? Is it polynomial time?